# How to make logstah public over the network

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Need your support, As the below image I configure ELK and deploy it in a separate server. it's working inside the same server but I'm trying to access Logstash over the same network on other servers.

> **My question is possible on local env?.**

Logstash Configuration

```
# Read input from filebeat by listening to port 5044 on which filebeat will send the data
input {
    beats {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => "5044"
    }
}
  
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    # Sending properly parsed log events to elasticsearch
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "e-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

File Beats Configuration

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true
  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    #- /var/log/*.log
    - E:\IMR-App\imrh\logs\imrh.log
# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["0.0.0.0:5044"]
```

[image]

Comment: What is your pipeline configuration? What input you are using? This is pretty common for network inputs (beats, tcp, udp etc), you just need to configure the input to listen to the logstash ip address instead of logstash. Update your question with your configuration

Comment: Also make sure you don't have firewall rules preventing outbound traffic from server1/2 and inbound traffic on server3:5044